# Sum of cells with same row and column name in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix created using `table()` command in R in which rows and columns do not have same values.

```
       0   1   2 
  1    1   2   3  
  2    4   5   6  
  3    7   7   8
```

How can I sum the elements with the same row and column name? In this example it is equal to (2+6=)8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# find the values present in both row names and column names
is <- do.call(intersect, unname(dimnames(x)))

# calculate the sum
sum(x[cbind(is, is)])
```

where `x` is your table.

Comment: I like the use of `intersect` and passing to `cbind` to make a character index, but couldn't see the need for `unname`.

Comment: @DWin Try it with `x <- table(data.frame(a=rep(1:3, 4), b = sample(0:2, 12, TRUE)))` and without `unname`.

Answer (score 1):

Another one, self-explanatory:

```
sum(x[colnames(x)[col(x)] == rownames(x)[row(x)]])
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant one